# Refractoring a nested query in Linq to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Supposing I have this query:

```
var ps = from p in dc.Products
         let text =
             (from t in p.Text
              orderby t.Language == "ja" descending
              select t).FirstOrDefault()
         select new { p.Id, text.Name };
```

Is there any way to refractor the query being assigned to `text`?

My guess is that I need to make it an `Expression<Func<Product, string, ProductText>>`, but I don't know how I'd invoke it.

By the way, if there are more efficient ways to do this, I'd be happy to know.

Thanks,

Rei

**Edit:** To clarify, the idea is that if Japanese isn't available, I want it to fall back on whatever other language is available.

Maybe this is more efficient?

```
let text = p.Text.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Language == "ja") ?? p.Text.FirstOrDefault()
```

Either way, my main question is about how I might make `text` query reusable -- because it's rather unintuitive, and I can picture myself or someone else doing it wrong in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED BASED ON COMMENT**

```
var ps = dc.Products.Select(p => new 
{
    Id = p.Id, 
    Text = p.Text.OrderBy(t=> t.Language == "ja").First()
})
.Select (x => new
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name,
    ...
});
```

Comment: Not quite, because I want it to fall back on whatever language is available. Also, it's likely that I'll be wanting more than just `Name` -- hence the `let`.

Comment: Makes sense, although I suspect you'd really want to fall back to a specific language rather than some random one??  How about the edited version then?  Although now it's pretty much identical to what you started with.

Comment: Hmm yeah, that looks quite close to my first one. I'm guessing the executed query is pretty much the same. Falling back to a particular language would be good (probably English), but I'll probably worry about that later if I ever end up with a third language. Should be able to just add a `then by fallbackPriority` or something along those lines. Right now I'm only worried about Japanese and English.